# jackson serialize class literal

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class:

```
package my.package;
public class TreeItem{
    ...
}
```

When I want to serialize a Class literal like `TreeItem.class` the jackson serializes it as:

```
"class my.package.TreeItem"
```

I want to serialize it as

```
"my.package.TreeItem"
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class TreeConfigMap extends HashMap<Class<? extends TreeItem>, Map<String, Object>>{
  //empty
}
```

TreeController:  (a rest controller)

```
@RequestMapping("/config")
public TreeConfigMap config(...){
  TreeConfigMap config= new TreeConfigMap();
  Map<String,Object> m = new HashMap<>();
  m.put("ali","gholi");
  config.put(TreeItem.class,m);
  return config;
}
```

The output is:

```
{"class my.package.TreeItem":{"ali":"gholi"}}
```

Comment: Can you please share code snippet where you are serializing to produce the output "class my.package.TreeItem"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom key serializer.

Annotate your TreeConfigMap to use custom key serializer

```
@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = ClassNameSerializer.class)
public static class TreeConfigMap extends HashMap<Class<? extends TreeItem>, Map<String, Object>>{
      //empty
}
```

Alternatively, you register the serializer with ObjectMapper

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addKeySerializer(Class.class, new ClassNameSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
    ...
    mapper.writeValueAsString(treeConfigMap)
```

Here is serializer code

```
public static class ClassNameSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Class> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Class value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeFieldName(value.getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit your answer such that you solve the problem by jackson custom ObejctMapper (by maybe adding a SimpleModule)

Comment: Done.  Not sure how it will plug into your serialization to JSON being done by the REST framework, as my example uses Mapper explicitly

Comment: Thanks again! I know how to plug it into my spring mvc app.